# Can I use conditional logic in PHP EOD?

Tags: php

Is it possible to put conditional logic inside an EOD string?

```
$str = <<<EOD

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            if ( !empty($var1) ) {
                {$var1}
            } else {
                {$var2}
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This doesn't work for me, and it sort of looks like it wouldn't work, but I thought I'd take a stab.

Also,  is it `EOD` or `EOT`? Both seem to work.

Comment: It's actually [HEREDOC](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/2/6/3). ) And no, you cannot use conditional logic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You cannot use conditionals in [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

> Also, is it `EOD` or `EOT`?

As long as your beginning and ending strings match you can use anything:

```
 $x = <<<THOMAS
 Pick a string, any string
 THOMAS;
```

The doc [contains several examples demonstrating this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-74)

As to how best to achieve the example you provided, this would be my first inclination:

```
$td = !empty($var1) ? $var1 : $var2;
$str = <<<EOD
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {$td}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
EOD;
```

Comment: Ha! I like it. I think I'll use that :) Thanks

Comment: So the best way is just to close the string and do the condition and if it's true to concatenate the <<<THOMAS if the variable is not empty, in your opinion?